# How do I change the width of the vertical header column for Q3Table in qt 4.3?

Tags: c++, qt, qt4

I am using a `Q3Table` object and wanted to change the width of the vertical header column. Does anyone know how to do this? It seems I can only adjust the height of the header cell but not the width.

Answer (score 2):

You want to use Q3Table::setLeftMargin. This will set the width of the vertical header.

> void Q3Table::setLeftMargin ( int m )
> Sets the left margin to be m pixels wide. 
> The verticalHeader(), which displays row labels, occupies this margin.